# Mirror full Grails plugin repository for offline access?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, artifactory

I will be traveling for a period of time and have no network connectivity for 1-2 weeks. I'd like to be productive during this time, and having offline access to the Grails plugin repository would really help.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've seen some reference trying Artifactory, but no reports of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article which might help you achieve what you are after http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2012/06/04/seriously-offline-grails-going-totally-sans-internet-with-nexus.html

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a step in the right direction, but as I understand it Nexus (or Artifactory for that matter) will only cache those plugins I use ahead of time, before disconnecting. What I'd like to do is have a cache of *all* available plugins. I suppose one way to do this would be to use the linked setup with a project which installs all available plugins via BuildConfig.groovy, but I imagine it'd be very difficult to create such a project. Any ideas?

Comment: This kinda worked for me. However, it didn't cache all necessary plugins, so I ended up being unable to use certain ones I didn't foresee ahead of time. As long as you configure your project to use all plugins you think you'll need and then follow the linked article it should work. If you don't know which plugins you need, you're out of luck.

It'd really be nice if future releases provided a way to mirror the entire plugin repository, like apt-mirror gives you for Debian/Ubuntu packages.